# Accessing Azure Devops on premises via Visual Studio

Tags: azure-devops, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I had installed `Azure Devops` on our `Windows 2019` server. The server has 5 users and all of them were created as local users on the server. I added these 5 users in Dev Ops project. Four of these users started using visual studio directly on the same server and have cloned project from on premises Azure dev ops. When they connected to the Azure dev ops server, they simply used User1, User2.... username and their windows password to connect to the Azure.

After a couple of weeks, we implemented `Active Directory` and added this server into the active directory group. The existing four users are still able to pull, push the same project. However, when the fifth user which never logged in now needs to connect to the Azure Dev Ops to clone the project. When he tries to connect via Visual Studio, the visual studio adds Domain into the user name e.g. DomainName\User5 and azure dev ops connectivity is not accepting his windows password. This user is not a domain user and is local to the server. This user can login to Azure Dev Ops when accessing it from browser, but unable to connect when trying it from Visual Studio.

Also, when I logged in directly to Azure Dev Ops (on premises) and try to add members to project, it does not show domain users. It only shows local server users.

Do I need to reinstall Azure dev ops, what should be the apprpriate way to fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When the fifth tried to use Visual Studio to connect the project, and access the project on web browser, did he do these things also directly on the same server machine?

Due the fifth user can access the project on web browser, the account of this user should not have issue. The problem seems occurs on Visual Studio when trying the authentication for the account.

Please try to check with the following things to see if the problem can be solved:

1. Check if the user has login to Visual Studio with his account.
2. Check if Visual Studio has saved or cached the account information of other users. If yes, clean the cache. Then login to Visual Studio with the fifth user's account.
3. When trying to connect to the project on Visual Studio, make sure the the selected user id the fifth user.

[image]

If the issue still exists, please share us with the details error message that the fifth user gets.